# Как правильно импортировать и экспортировать DLL C++ в C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Я не особо опытен (читай: совсем не опытен) в работе с библиотеками, т.к. еще только изучаю ЯП. Я пытался повторять, копипастить, задавать вопросы знающим знакомым. Ничего не помогло. Я имею код на C++, в котором находятся классы, образующие файловую систему. Если это так можно назвать... Структура с вектором этаких же структур, а также каждая имеет вектор файлов. А на C# я хочу сделать UI. Не знаю о чем думал преподаватель когда просил его сделать на C++. Полазив, понял, что я еще "недорос". Принялся искать возможные варианты. Нашел пару статей про DLL, попробовал, но так ни разу и не смог сделать все верно. Если не найду выход придется делать "общение"... Не знаю даже как. Поможете?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int hasher(string x)
{
    int StringLength, HashKey, i, tmp;
    StringLength = strlen(x.c_str()); 
    HashKey = 0;
    if (StringLength % 2 == 0) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < StringLength; i = i + 2)
        {
            tmp = x[i];
            tmp = tmp * 90000000;
            tmp = tmp + x[i + 1];
            HashKey = HashKey + tmp;
        }
    }
    if (StringLength % 2 != 0) 
    {
        for (i = 1; i < StringLength - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            tmp = x[i];
            tmp = tmp * 90000000;
            tmp = tmp + x[i + 1];
            HashKey = HashKey + tmp;
        }
        HashKey = HashKey + x[0];
    } 
    return (HashKey);
}

char* KeyGeneration(short len) {
    short cont(0);
    char let[66] = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm-+_";
    char* code;
    code = new char[len];
    string codestr;
    for (int i(0); i != len; i++) {
        code[i] = let[rand() % 66];
    }
    return code;
}


class User {
protected:
    int password;
    char* keyID;
public:
    string login;
    int maxRule;
    int ID;
    bool Login(string lg, string pw) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pw += pw;
        }
        int hash = hasher(pw);
        if (lg == login and hash == password) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    string gethash() { return to_string(password); }

};

class _user : public User {
public:
    _user(string lg, string pw) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pw += pw;
        }
        password = hasher(pw);
        login = lg;
        ID = rand() % 9999 + 1000;
        
        keyID = new char[2000];
        keyID = KeyGeneration(2000);
        
        maxRule = 0;
    }
    
};

class ADMIN : public User {
public:
    ADMIN(string lg, string pw) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pw += pw;
        }
        password = hasher(pw);
        login = lg;
        ID = rand() % 9999 + 1000;
        cout << ID;
        keyID = new char[20000];
        keyID = KeyGeneration(20000);
        maxRule = 1002;
    }
private:

};


bool Login(vector<User> users, string lg, string pw, User& Set) {
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        if (users[i].Login(lg, pw)) {
            Set = users[i];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


class sttable {

public:
    vector<string> data;
    vector<string> names;
    sttable() {};
    void addt(string name, string dt);
    string getData(string name);
};
void sttable::addt(string name, string dt) {
    names.push_back(name);
    data.push_back(dt);
}
string sttable::getData(string name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        if (names[i] == name) {
            return data[i];
        }
    }
    return "0";
}
string shipher(string str, string pass) {
    string retval;
    int p;
    retval.resize(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        p = i % pass.length();
        retval[i] = str[i] ^ pass[i % pass.length()];
    }
    return retval;
}


class sFile {
    string Data = "";

    sttable thr;
    int password;
    string hash;

public:
    int minRule = 0;
    string name;
    string path;
    int created;
    int modified;
    sFile() {
        password = 1;
        name = "newfile";
        created = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    };
    sFile(string name, string data) {
        this->name = name;
        password = 1;
        Data = "CHECKER";
        thr.addt("MAIN", shipher(data, to_string(password)));
        thr.addt("CHEK", shipher(Data, to_string(password)));
        created = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
    sFile(string name, string data, string* key) {//-1356925440
        this->name = name;
        string k = *key;
        password = rand();
        Data = "CHECKER";
        thr.addt("MAIN", shipher(data, to_string(password)));
        thr.addt("CHEK", shipher(Data, to_string(password)));
        created = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        string buf = shipher(to_string(password), *key);
        key = &buf;
        thr.addt("PAS0", *key);
        hash = *key;

    }
    string getcheck() {
        return thr.getData("CHEK");
    }
    string getdata() {
        return thr.getData("MAIN");
    }
    string gethash() {
        return hash;
    }
};

struct Gallery {
    string path;
    string galleryName;
    vector<struct Gallery> inner;
    vector<sFile> files;
};





class FileSys {
    Gallery system;

public:
    Gallery* opened = &system;
    FileSys() {
        system.galleryName = "$/";
        opened = &system;
        system.path = system.galleryName;
    }
    bool newGallery(Gallery& where, string name) {
        int res;
        Gallery bufer;
        bufer.galleryName = name + "/";
        bufer.path = where.path + bufer.galleryName;
        where.inner.push_back(bufer);
        return true;
    }
    bool newFile(Gallery& where, string name) {
        int res;
        sFile bufer(name + ".fl", "data");
        bufer.path = where.path + bufer.name;
        where.files.push_back(bufer);
        return true;
    }
    string newFile(Gallery& where, string name, User user) {
        string res = user.gethash();
        sFile bufer(name + ".fl", "data", &res);
        bufer.path = where.path + bufer.name;
        where.files.push_back(bufer);
        return res;
    }
    string newFile(Gallery& where, string name, User user, string in, int min) {
        string res = user.gethash();
        sFile bufer(name + ".fl", in, &res);
        bufer.minRule = min;
        bufer.path = where.path + bufer.name;
        where.files.push_back(bufer);
        return res;
    }

};

Gallery* getInner(Gallery* where, string name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < where->inner.size(); i++) {
        if (where->inner[i].galleryName == name) { where = &where->inner[i]; return where; }
    }

    return where;

}
sFile openFile(Gallery where, string name, User user) {

    for (int i = 0; i < where.files.size(); i++) {
        if (where.files[i].name == name and user.maxRule >= where.files[i].minRule) { return where.files[i]; }
    }
    sFile err;
    return err;

}

string processFile(sFile file, User user) {
    string data;
    string pass = shipher(file.gethash(), user.gethash());
    if (shipher(file.getcheck(), "1") == "CHECKER") {
        data = shipher(file.getdata(), "1");
    }
    else if (shipher(file.getcheck(), pass) == "CHECKER") {
        data = shipher(file.getdata(), pass);
    }

    return data;
}

//----------------------//
```

что - то подобное было на входе. спустя 1e15 попыток вышло это:

```
#ifdef PFS_DLL
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C" EXPORT int hasher(string x);

extern "C" EXPORT char* KeyGeneration(short len);


extern "C" class EXPORT User {
protected:
    int password;
    char* keyID;
public:
    string login;
    int maxRule;
    int ID;
    bool Login(string lg, string pw);
    string gethash();

};

extern "C" class EXPORT _user : public User {
public:
    _user(string lg, string pw);
    //bool Login(string lg, string pw) : Login(lg, pw) {}
};

extern "C" class EXPORT ADMIN : public User {
public:
    ADMIN(string lg, string pw);
private:

};


extern "C" EXPORT bool Login(vector<User> users, string lg, string pw, User& Set);


extern "C" class EXPORT sttable {

public:
    vector<string> data;
    vector<string> names;
    sttable() {};
    void addt(string name, string dt);
    string getData(string name);
};

extern "C" EXPORT string shipher(string str, string pass);


extern "C" class EXPORT sFile {
    string Data = "";

    sttable thr;
    int password;
    string hash;

public:
    int minRule = 0;
    string name;
    string path;
    int created;
    int modified;
    sFile();
    sFile(string name, string data);
    sFile(string name, string data, string* key);
    string getcheck();
    string getdata();
    string gethash();
};

extern "C" struct EXPORT Gallery {
    string path;
    string galleryName;
    vector<struct Gallery> inner;
    vector<sFile> files;
};

/*
Gallery searchgalleries(Gallery core, int* result, string address) {

    Gallery buf = core;
    Gallery err;
    err.galleryName = "nullptr";
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.galleryName.length(); i++) {
        if (address[i] == buf.galleryName[i]) {
            address.erase(address.begin());
        }
        else {
            return err;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < buf.inner.size(); j++) {
        string add = address;
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.galleryName.length(); i++) {
            if (address[i] == buf.galleryName[i]) {
                add.erase(add.begin());
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (add == "") return buf;
        if (buf.inner.size() < j) buf = buf.inner[j];
        else return err;
    }



}
*/


extern "C" class EXPORT FileSys {
    Gallery system;

public:
    Gallery* opened = &system;
    FileSys();
    bool newGallery(Gallery& where, string name);
    bool newFile(Gallery& where, string name);
    string newFile(Gallery& where, string name, User user);
    string newFile(Gallery& where, string name, User user, string in, int min);

};

extern "C" EXPORT Gallery * getInner(Gallery * where, string name);


extern "C" EXPORT sFile openFile(Gallery where, string name, User user);


extern "C" EXPORT string processFile(sFile file, User user);

//----------------------//
```

Собраться оно собралось, но вот на примере функции hasher:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: "Не удается найти точку входа "hasher" в DLL "Dll_PFS.dll"."

Если вас тошнит при виде моего кода - не ругайте, пожалуйста, по мере возрастания количества попыток код стал походить на фарш.

Очень надеюсь на вашу доброту и помощь.

Comment: "код стал походить на фарш" - это точно... так что начать следовало бы составив [mcve]

Comment: @user7860670 Извините, первый мой вопрос тут. Буду знать. Есть ли какие нибудь идеи?

Comment: Идея есть. Создайте либу с одним методом, по всем канонам, вложите в метод что-то простое, например, пусть он инвертирует `bool` и возвращает результат. Попробуйте ее прикрутить. И если не получится, выкладывайте сюда код вашего минимального воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1050117/206435 возможно как-то поможет...

Comment: Когда-то я тоже решал подобный вопрос. Может и вам поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444146/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%a1-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-cpp-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-c